# Using a variable within str.contains()

Tags: python, pandas

Pretty much the title.  Any way to use a variable to filter in str.contain()?  i have been unsuccessful in using a str+@variable

Comment: I'm not sure what language yours comes from, but the correct syntax for `fr'\b{{@unique_value}}\b'` is `fr'\b{unique_value}\b'` in python....

Comment: i tried it also and did not work @BeRT2me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var = 'test'
df = df[df['test_col'].str.contains(var)]
```

This should work!